# Mat-Select how to remove the little zoom

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-select

I'm using the [mat-select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) from angular material and I would like to disable the little zoom effect when entering in the selection of items ?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example

As you can see in the stackblitz link above, when you beggin to click to the input field there is a sort of list that come in top and there is a small bump to enphasize the selection items. How can I remove this bump with CSS ?

Didn't find anything in the material support nor somewhere else.

I think there is something to be changed in the class cdk-overlay-0 but I don't know what.

At the end, I would like that my Mat-select behave as below :
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally sorted out by changing my strategy. Instead of mat-select, I'm using autocomplete with some customization

```
<form class="example-form">
 <input type="text" class="input" (change)="control()" placeholder=" {{options[selectedId].name}}" [formControl]="myControl" #trigger="matAutocompleteTrigger" [matAutocomplete]="auto" (click)="reset( trigger, auto)">
 <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.name" (click)="selected(option.id)">
      {{option.name}}
    </mat-option>
 </mat-autocomplete>
</form>
```

With autocomplete, I'm able to create a list without any bump and in addition you have a searchable list :)